# Deploy flask-socketio on beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, flask-socketio

I can't quite get Flask-SocketIO working with my instance on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (ELB), with the requirement of running Flask-SocketIO with socketio.run(application), ELB appears to make the calls to the global application object itself.

The ELB documentation states Using application.py as the filename and providing a callable application object (the Flask object, in this case) allows Elastic Beanstalk to easily find your application's code.

My ELB instance logs show the error RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.

Is there any way to approach this problem assuming that AWS calls application.run()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Flask-SocketIO has very specific requirements on the load balancer and the web server. I think you can configure the ELB load balancer with sticky sessions and that would make it work, but the part that I think does not work is using the eventlet or gevent web servers, since AWS invokes the callable in its own way. What you need is a way to use `socketio.run()` or an equivalent procedure that starts the eventlet/gevent web server.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some changes to AWS beanstalk lately. Per default it uses gunicorn and nginx.

I got the setup working using a single instance setup without loadbalancers. The loadbalancer config in beanstalk allows stickiness configuration but my applications design would work only on a single instance anyway, so I didn't care.

To create a single instance beanstalk environment:

```
eb create --single my_env
```

Then, configure the way gunicorn is started: Create a file `Procfile` (see [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/python-configuration-procfile.html))

For `eventlet` use this:

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 application:application
```

And place this into requirements.txt:

```
gunicorn==20.1.0
eventlet==0.30.2
```

The particular versions are needed to prevent the `cannot import name 'ALREADY_HANDLED'` error, see [here](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/702).

See [flask-socketio doc](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html) for other deployment options besides gunicorn/eventlet.